# Custom layout based on the attribute set not working

Tags: product, layout, layout-update, product-page

I've followed [this tutorial](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/) to add `attribute set` specific product page layout updates, but  it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

file: `app\code\local\Magebase\AttributeSetHandle\etc\config.xml`

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magebase_AttributeSetHandle>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magebase_AttributeSetHandle>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <attributesethandle>
                        <class>Magebase_AttributeSetHandle_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addAttributeSetHandle</method>
                    </attributesethandle>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

File: `app\code\local\Magebase\AttributeSetHandle\Model\Observer.php`

CODE:

```
<?php
class Magebase_AttributeSetHandle_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Converts attribute set name of current product to nice name ([a-z0-9_]+).
     * Adds layout handle PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_<attribute_set_nicename> after
     * PRODUCT_TYPE_<product_type_id> handle
     *
     * Event: controller_action_layout_load_before
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function addAttributeSetHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        /**
         * Return if it is not product page
         */
        if (!($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) {
            return;
        }

        $attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
        /**
         * Convert attribute set name to alphanumeric + underscore string
         */
        $niceName = str_replace('-', '_', $product->formatUrlKey($attributeSet->getAttributeSetName()));

        /* @var $update Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update */
        $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $handles = $update->getHandles(); // Store all handles in a variable
        $update->resetHandles(); // Remove all handles

        /**
         * Rearrange layout handles to ensure PRODUCT_<product_id>
         * handle is added last
         */
        foreach ($handles as $handle) {
            $update->addHandle($handle);
            if ($handle == 'PRODUCT_TYPE_' . $product->getTypeId()) {
                $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_' . $niceName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `local.xml` inside the `<layout></layout>` i've added:

```
<PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Informatica>
    <reference name="product.info">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view-informatica.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Informatica>
```

My attribute set is named `Informatica` and the customized view.phtml is located in `design/frontend/[my-custom-tample]/default/template/catalog/product`

What am I missing here?

Please help :)

Thanks guys,

Comment: remove $update->resetHandles(); // Remove all handles

Comment: done, but nothing happens... Still the same layout? Cleared cache, reindexed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first need debug your `current page handler` by below code:

```
Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

I have modify code and add the **handler only for product view page**

```
<?php
class Magebase_AttributeSetHandle_Model_Observer
{
    public function addAttributeSetHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='catalog_product_view'){
            $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
            if($product):
            $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
            $attributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
            $handle = str_replace('-', '_', $product->formatUrlKey($attributeSet->getAttributeSetName()));

            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_'.$handle);
            // check all Handler 
            //Zend_Debug::dump($layout->getUpdate()->getHandles());
            endif;
        }
        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's what comes out: array(11) {
  [0] => string(7) "default"
  [1] => string(8) "STORE_es"
  [2] => string(28) "THEME_frontend_tytes_default"
  [3] => string(20) "catalog_product_view"
  [4] => string(19) "PRODUCT_TYPE_simple"
  [5] => string(33) "PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_informatica"
  [6] => string(10) "PRODUCT_77"
  [7] => string(19) "customer_logged_out"
  [8] => string(19) "MAP_price_msrp_item"
  [9] => string(14) "SHORTCUT_popup"
  [10] => string(17) "SHORTCUT_uk_popup"
}

Comment: you see your handler is PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_informatica but you used PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_Informatica

Comment: Done, please modify it, specify that the uppercase is important :) For further solution seekers ;) Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @AmitBera could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221316/57334

Comment: Sure, i will look