# Manage Attribute Sets :: How to solve Magento 1.9.2.3 Unassigned Attributes Fields Empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-set

After added new attributes, Unassigned Attributes field is empty, ver Magento 1.9.2.3

[image]

**Note : What are all the possibilities of error?**

Comment: Please check attribute save or not?

Comment: Yes, it is saved

Comment: FYI : https://snag.gy/QHEr7j.jpg

Comment: Delete it and add once again and check it.

Comment: I tried that, no use,,

Comment: Did you reindexed ?

Comment: @Magento2Learner yes, i reindexed.

Comment: @Magento2Learner  may i know the possibilities of error?

Comment: did you checked system.log ? is there any error in that ? 
console error ?

Comment: Finally found the solution, the error is PATCH_SUPEE-10570, after successfully reverted now working. May i know how can i solve the PATCH_SUPEE-10570 issue?